# What is the most recent measure of the US Municipal Bond Market Size (Capitalization)?

Tags: fixed-income, portfolio-management, bond, bond-yields, market-capitalization

$3.853 trillion in second quarter of 2018 according to Fed. Today?

Comment: 3.815763 in Q1 2019. Q2 estimate should be out soon https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DNSMSL